# How to derive all offered interface types from an COM idl?

Tags: c#, com, ole

My goals is to generate bridging code that allows to call a COM interface in Java.  I do use successfully JNA, insofar as I get an handle to the interface and can successfully work with most of the functionality of the interface.

I have a question regarding several interfaces that are similar to the following pattern (I think the snippet is self-contained):

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(4D27AA78-B622-42E7-A237-3DA76B14A23D),
  helpstring("IVariables Interface"),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface IVariables : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), propget, helpstring("property Application")]
    HRESULT Application([out, retval] IDispatch** pVal);
    [id(0x00000002), propget, helpstring("property Parent")]
    HRESULT Parent([out, retval] IDispatch** pVal);
    [id(0x00000003), propget, helpstring("property Count")]
    HRESULT Count([out, retval] long* pnCount);
    [id(00000000), propget, helpstring("property Item")]
    HRESULT Item(
                    [in] VARIANT index, 
                    [out, retval] IVariable** pVal);
    [id(0xfffffffc), propget, helpstring("property _NewEnum")]
    HRESULT _NewEnum([out, retval] IUnknown** ppEnum);
    [id(0x00000004), helpstring("method Add")]
    HRESULT Add(
                    [in] BSTR Name, 
                    [in, optional] VARIANT Value, 
                    [out, retval] IVariable** pVal);
    [id(0x00000005), helpstring("method Remove")]
    HRESULT Remove([in] VARIANT index);
};
```

If this interface is imported into Visual Studio and used in a C# project, then C# detects that the above implements the interface [IEnumerator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/ienumerator.cs,6624f38cb955bfe0) and allows to iterate over the elements. Moreover C# even knows the iterated type, being an 'IVariable'.

**Q1: How does C# or its COM-interface importer draw the conclusion that 'IVariables' above implements 'IEnumerator' and the enumerated elements are of type 'IVariable'?**

Obviously the line

```
[id(0xfffffffc), propget, helpstring("property _NewEnum")]
```

must do the trick.  But while I found the same construct in other IDLs, I cannot find any explanation on this in Google.  Maybe related is that I get no information whatsoever on the types of properties from the IDL, see

```
    [id(0x00000002), propget, helpstring("property Parent")]
```

in the above IDL.  There is neither a type 'Parent' nor a type 'IParent'.  Thus:

**Q2: Is it possible to derive the type of a COM property from its IDL and if yes how?**

Finally, when importing the above types into C# the above IDL is actually not used.  Instead the importer expects the executable for the OLE-enabled application, to read its typelib (similar to the Microsoft oleview.exe tool).  This leads me to my last question:

**Q3: Is there an API that can be used to query the OLE interface of an executable and does this offer addditional metadata?**

Thanks for insights.

Comment: It is not C# that does this, it is the type library importer.  Tlbimp.exe is the standalone tool, the interop library it generates has the plumbing to give it a C#-like interface.  Dispid -4 is the equivalent of GetEnumerator(), Dispid 0 is the indexer from which it derived the element type.  A managed version of tlbimp was published at Codeplex, I think it is [here now](https://github.com/clrinterop/TypeLibraryImporter).  Its kinda beefy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) because the dispid is a well-known one: [DISPID_NEWENUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/cb9d0131-c6bd-463d-9c40-7264856a10c5) (-4) that designates an enumerator. The item's type (`IVariable`) can be deduced from the `Item` (the indexer) member which uses 0 (DISPID_VALUE).

> DISPID_NEWENUM -4
>
> This MUST designate the DISPID associated with a
>   _NewEnum method that MUST have the following signature.
>
> HRESULT _NewEnum([out,retval] IEnumVARIANT** ppenum);
>
> or
>
> HRESULT _NewEnum([out,retval] IUnknown** ppenum);

2) yes, if the property type is specified in the idl (duh), but here you're looking at a pure late-binding interface (`IDispatch` only), which is fully dynamic, so no, in this case.

3) `.IDL` is not used because the `.TLB` format is equivalent, and programmable through [ITypeLib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-itypelib) et al. Only the MIDL compiler uses IDL. At runtime, there's not much more than the TLB available in the general case. COM in its simplest form basically only needs `IUnknown` and that's it.